# Strange behavior of apply-Please correct me

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a function for generating a matrix of 0 & 1 like this:

```
sim<-function(b,n){
t<-sort(rnorm(n))
p<-sapply(1:length(b),function(i) 1/(1+exp(b[i]-t)))
y<-runif(length(b)*n)
return(ifelse(p>y,1,0))
}
```

in which `b` is a vector. Another fun is defined to manipulate a vector as below:

```
SH<-function(x){
it<-sort(sample(1:length(x),ceiling(0.25*length(x))))
x0<-x
x0[it]<-1
return(x0)}
```

for instance, on a vector like `c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0)` the `SH` may return something like this:

```
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Now,with a `b` vector like this:

```
b<-seq(-3,3,len=10)
```

and `n=50` the results of `sim` is a 50 by 10 matrix. I tried to apply `SH` on the rows of generated matrix by `sim` as:

```
data<-sim(b,50)
data2<-apply(data,1,SH)
```

but the matrix returned by `apply` is of size 10 by 50.I supposed that it should return a matrix of size 50 by 10 in which its row are manipulated by `SH`.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `data2<-apply(data,MARGIN = 2,SH)`

Comment: @Alex doesn't your code apply `SH` over columns of `data` and not its rows?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry, misread the example. I ran the code, it seems to return a matrix of 10 by 50. Does it seem like each column is the answer to SH applied to a row of data?

Comment: Ah, the answer is in ?apply:     If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’
     returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’. i.e. SH returns a vector of length 10, and `dim(data)[1]` is 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data2` is a 10 by 50 matrix. The i-th column of the matrix is the result of applying `SH` to the i-th row, as obtained from the help file for apply:

```
  If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’
 returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’.
```

To return the matrix of size 50 by 10 such that each row corresponds to applying `SH` to the corresponding row in `data`, transpose:

```
data2 = t(apply(data,1,SH))
```

Comment: This is kind of weird.Is there a way to generate a manipulated matrix with the same dimensions of original matrix with transposing the result?

Comment: well, actually this behaviour seems normal. In essence apply returns a vector of length equal to number of rows or columns, depending on the choice of `MARGIN`. However, a decision must be made on formatting the output if the each element of the vector is a vector itself. There may well be a different apply type function, however.

Comment: I see.Another solution that I came up with, which is also faster than `apply` on big matrices, is using `sapply` in this form `t(sapply(1:50,function(i) SH(data[i,])))`